# Why do some shapefiles (e.g., state-level in US) have different default "zoom levels" to others?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

Why is it that [this](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/tiger-line-shapefile-2013-state-washington-current-county-subdivision-state-based) shapefile of Washington state, when loaded into QGIS or via D3, appears large and zoomed in, like below:
[image]

Meanwhile, others, such as [this](https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm) Zillow neighborhoods shapefile ( also for Washington state), when loaded, looks thus:
[image]

While the first shapefile was loaded at the correct, state scale, the second, neighbourhoods file was loaded at an incorrect scale — a national one. For reference, here's what it looks like at the appropriate scale:

[image]

Is there any way to control this behaviour? Can I ensure that the Zillow shapefile of Washington state's neighborhoods loads at a larger, more zoomed in scale?

**edit:** this happens with geojson and topojson too.

Comment: It's because of the Feature Extent that's stored in the shapefile..you could try exporting the shapefile again from the layer and it should rebuild the spatial extent and index, another suggestion is to start editing and make a very minor  and reversible change, save, fix and save edits again. the save action should recalculate the feature extent. Of course there could be a very small flyaway polygon on the lower right, try selecting the visible polygons, switch selection and see if there's one selected.

Comment: Or some small polygon far away from the others which you cant see in small scale.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:geojson]?

Answer (score 5):

Because in that dataset there is one feature that is very far from the other ones.

[image]

Comment: Oddly, even when you remove all other polygons from that shapefile and save as a new layer, this problem persists. I've tried to isolate Seattle in this way but I continue to get the same zoomed out view.